# Windows terminal run multiple commands in multiple tabs on startup

Tags: python, shortcut, windows-terminal

So I use a bunch of python scripts to do a bunch of stuff in the background on my PC, but I think it's a hassle to set it up each time I start my computer, so I tried to do a shortcut that would launch all these scripts in several terminal tabs in the same window.
I tried to do it with a shortcut that looked like this:
`wt ; new-tab -p "Command Prompt" "absolute path to the python script"` although each time I tried that it gave me this error 0x800700c1. I also tried to create a profile with a python prompt (that would automatically start at the right location) I could import my script in to, same error, and I tried removing the `new-tab -p "command prompt` altogether bc it's the default profilr, but here it just ended up creating two windows, one of which had this error still in it.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: `0x800700c1` is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`. Are you absolutely sure the commandline is correct? 

_<psychic debugging>_: are you setting the commandline as `python.exe my_script.py`, or just `my_script.py`? Because the second definitely won't work.

Comment: I tried both. Both work in normal command prompt circumstances, when executing them by hand, none work in the shortcut.